# how to insert values to a new column in SQL when other columns are defined as not null?

Tags: sql

i have created a table with 3 columns in which 2 are defined as NOT NULL in SQL, now i created a new column i wanted to insert values to only the new variable, but i'm having an error while using Insert into statement

Comment: Which RDBMS is this for? Please add a tag to specify whether you're using `mysql`, `postgresql`, `sql-server`, `oracle` or `db2` - or something else entirely.

Comment: You cannot treat table cells as "variables" in a RDBMS. You can only insert or change _rows_ which means you have to fill _all_ columns.

Comment: In general: please be precise in your question. Instead of writing "i'm having an error" please be _specific_, post the _exact_ error message you get.

Comment: please look here on how to improve question and get fast answers :https://spaghettidba.com/2015/04/24/how-to-post-a-t-sql-question-on-a-public-forum/

Comment: You are looking for `UPDATE` not insert

Answer (score 0):

If you are using MySQL, here is your answer:

> Inserting NULL into a column that has been declared NOT NULL. For multiple-row INSERT statements or INSERT INTO ... SELECT statements, the column is set to the implicit default value for the column data type. This is 0 for numeric types, the empty string ('') for string types, and the “zero” value for date and time types. INSERT INTO ... SELECT statements are handled the same way as multiple-row inserts because the server does not examine the result set from the SELECT to see whether it returns a single row. (For a single-row INSERT, no warning occurs when NULL is inserted into a NOT NULL column. Instead, the statement fails with an error.)

The documentation is here: [MySQL 5.7 Reference Manual: Insert](http://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/5.7/en/insert.html)

As said above, just use ' ' and 0 depending on the type of column you have. I believe it's the same for any other DBMS system anyone could use.

Answer (score -1):

Disregarding that this normally indicates you should rethink your database design, some database engines will let you do this through temporary schema manipulation (removing and afterwards re-adding the 'not null' constraint).

Alternatively you could either define default values for the not null columns, or pass in through the insert command the appropriate "default" values, or select a database mode where either the checks are not enforced (thus allowing nulls) or default values are automatically generated (eg mysql in non strict mode which replaces the nulls with a calculated default value).

The only valid use case I can think of is replicating the situation where a database has rows with nulls in certain fields, and then the schema is changed to make those columns not null. Mysql for instance will allow you to add 'not null' constraints to columns that already have data with nulls in that column.